# Shell script to calculate average between columns in two different subsets

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have particular nasty shell programming to do with no to little experience in shell scripting. I have the following text file. What I need to do is to calculate the difference between the average Y(m) of subset 1 and the average Y(m) of subset 2. There can be more than two subsets, but it would be sufficient to calculate the difference between subset 1 and subset 2.

I have tried various awk commands but it seems my brain gets fried by too many obstacles. Arghhh!

```
MODEL PARAMETERS :
Project : Report
Dataset : xxx

Number of subsets    : 2
Total number         : 8

Subset number    : 1
Subset name      : xxx_sub1
Number           : 4

 NR   TYPE                       X(m)      Y(m)    Z(m)   Volume Pressure   CluNo     Activ  Group
 ---  ---------------------    ------    ------   -----  ------- --------   -----     -----  ------
   1  Type text                  0.00    -10.40    9.00   2000.0    500.0       0     0     1
   2  Type text                  0.00     -9.60    9.00   1000.0    500.0       0     1     1
   3  Type text                  3.00    -10.40    9.00   1200.0    500.0       1     1     1
   4  Type text                  3.00     -9.60    9.00    800.0    500.0       1     1     1

Subset number    : 2
Subset name      : xxx_sub2
Number           : 4

 NR   TYPE                       X(m)      Y(m)    Z(m)   Volume Pressure   CluNo Activ  Group
 ---  ---------------------    ------    ------   -----  ------- --------   ----- -----  ------
   1  Type text                  0.00     10.40   15.00   2000.0    500.0       0         0     1
   2  Type text                  0.00      9.60   15.00   1000.0    500.0       0     1     1
   3  Type text                  3.00     10.40   15.00   1200.0    500.0       1     1     1
   4  Type text                  3.00      9.60   15.00    800.0    500.0       1     1     1

Units : 
   Coordinates      : meter
   Volume           : cubic cm
   Pressure         : pascal
```

Basically I need average of the first set of Y(m) values: (-10.4-9.6-10.4-9.6)/4 = -10m and the average of the second set Y(m) values which is (10.4+9.6+10.4+9.6)/4= 10m and calculate the difference between both averages which is 20m.

Comment: `I have tried various awk commands but ...`.  Could you elaborate what did you try?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Y(m) has the same value on subset #1 and #2 except for the sign.  Give an example in what to calculate and we can extract it.

Answer (score 4):

It could be done with this script (tested with GNU Awk, on the above input):

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk -- '
    BEGIN {
        s = 0
        r = 0
    }

    /^Subset number/ {
        s = $4
        r = 0
    }

    /Type text/ {
        subset[s][r] = $5
        r++
    }

    END {
        for (s in subset) {
            subset_average[s] = 0
            for (r in subset[s]) {
                subset_average[s] += subset[s][r]
            }
            subset_average[s] /= length(subset[s])
        }
        print subset_average[2] - subset_average[1]
    }
'
```

It could be adapted to more subsets as well, by modifying the END block.

If "Type text" is just a replacement of real data in your example, then the data rows could be matched otherwise. Say by matching numbers at the start of a line, possibly preceded by blanks.

Comment: Nice, this is correct alternate way to do it with `awk` +1. Just a tip in `awk` you can rely on all variables being initialised to 0 so the `BEGIN` block is redundant.

Comment: That's looks quiet promising. I need it inside a large script so prefer it in #!/bin/sh. 

However the subset[s][r] gives me a syntax error. :(

Comment: @Cnoobplusplus - No!!! Do not try to do stuff like this in shell, it is NOT what the shell was created for and is best at. parsing text files is what awk was invented to do and has all of the builtin constructs to support.

Comment: @Ed Morton - Why??? You can call awk inside a shell script. Additionally I did not write the damn thing (otherwise everything would be written in C++) :D. I just need to modify it to comply with recent changes.

Comment: I thought when you said `I need it inside a large script so prefer it in #!/bin/sh` you were saying you wanted to re-write the awk script as shell to include it in a shell script. Sorry, apparently I misunderstood - you can run the awk script as-is from any bourne-based shell.

Comment: @Cnoobplusplus I've wrapped the above in to a bash script. You can supply the input through a redirection, or as an additional argument. The syntax error is probably due to awk not being GNU awk. Try installing GNU awk (the package is usually called gawk). The script is invoking GNU awk explicitly now.

Comment: @sudo_O Thanks :) I didn't know about the initialization to 0. I'll leave the BEGIN block there for those who don't know that, so it's clearer.

Comment: The `array[sub1][sub2]` syntax is only supported in newer versions of GNU awk. On other awks or older gawks you need to use `array[sub1,sub2]`. The difference is more than syntactic but it shouldn't matter for this example. Also - there are many things we could add to an awk script to cater to people who don't know awk but IMHO it's best to just write the language as intended and let them learn it as intended which in this case would mean removing the BEGIN block.

Comment: Okay thank you very much spbnick and Ed. After some changes I managed to get it up and running. This is the final code:

awk ' BEGIN {
    s=0
    r=0
}

/^Subset number/ {
    s++
    r=0
}

{
    if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) {
       r++
       yposset[s,r] = $(NF-7)
    }
}

END { 
    for (i=1; i<=s;i++) {
        yposset_average[i]=0
        for (j=1; j<=r;j++) {
            yposset_average[i] += yposset[i,j]
        }
        yposset_average[i] /= r
    }
    separation = yposset_average[1]-yposset_average[2]
    print separation<0 ? -separation : separation
} ' $inputfile

Comment: @EdMorton the `array[sub1,sub2]` approach wouldn't support `length(subset[s])` expression above. I would prefer explicit initialization even if I was sure about the implicit initialization, because it makes it somewhat easier to read. It is there for a reason similar to the one used in placing the /^Subset number/ pattern above /Type text/ pattern, even though it would work otherwise. It gives a visible reference point. I wouldn't do this in a one-liner probably, though.

Comment: @spbnick - wrt initing the variables, that's fine but then don't forget to initialize your array variables as well as your scalar variables for consistency. wrt `length(subset[s])` - yes, I didn't notice you were doing that. `r in subset[s]` would be a problem too. Looks like the OPs got his workaround anyway.

Comment: @EdMorton I wanted to initialize them, but haven't found how. There doesn't seem to be any array initializers in awk. Can you suggest a way? Thank you. Yes, I see that he's using the last dataset row number.

Comment: @spbnick to init a whole array in GNU awk is `delete(array)` and in other awks it's `split("",array)`. After that you need to decide how to init fields as you need them so, for example if you have `array[foo] += 7` then I guess you'd need to modify that to `if (!(foo in array)) array[foo] = 0; array[foo] += 7` or determine all possible array indices and init them all up front. <to be continued...>

Comment: <...continued> Initing any variable does have implications for how awk will behave when reading input, though. Awk itself inits variables to be `zero or null` then decides later on the type of that variable (number or string) based on how its first used and THEN gives it the appropriate initial value (zero or null) for that type of variable before operating on it. If you explicitly init a variable to zero (or "") then you inhibit awks ability to do that.

Comment: @EdMorton Understood. Thank you very much for the extensive answer, Ed.

Answer (score 2):

Given your structured file it's very easier to pick up the `Y(m)` columns and sum them. Each sum is stored in the array `a` where the key is the `Subset number`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(i=1;i<=$9;i++)a[$2]+=$(23+i*10+i);a[$2]/=$9}END{print a[2]-a[1]"m"}' RS='Subset number' file
20m
```

For two subsets just print the different between the two in the `END` block `a[1]-a[2]` that is the sum of subset `1` minus the sum of subset `2`. For more subsets just loop over each key and perform the calculation needed.

Comment: Perhaps I should have added that the subsets are not always 4 items long. This can vary. :D

Comment: Perhaps I should have mention my script picks up the length dynamically, see the max value for the for loop is `$9` not 4 and in the average `a[$2]/=$9` in fact my script doesn't contain a single 4.